# Problem in splitting a string using awk or cut command

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have a properties file which has a password field (key value pair)

```
PASSWORD=NDhhHcsOBofXUdUzGw5B0Q==
```

I am trying to get the value in my shell script using the `awk` command

```
password=`awk -F "=" '{if($1 == "PASSWORD") print $2}' "$PASSWORD.ini"`
```

But it retrieves only `NDhhHcsOBofXUdUzGw5B0Q`.

I need the entire password (including the last two `=`  characters).

Comment: Are you base64 encoding passwords?

Comment: @Evan, yes, that's base64 and if you look at the unencoded value, it's a 16 byte value, so probably a MD5 hash of the password.

Answer (score 5):

```
password=$(sed -n 's/^PASSWORD=//p' < "$PASSWORD.ini")
```

Answer (score 4):

Using awk:

```
password=$(awk 'sub(/^PASSWORD=/,"")' < "$PASSWORD.ini")
```

Answer (score 4):

`cut` would be the appropriate tool here if you already have the line extracted:

```
$ echo 'PASSWORD=NDhhHcsOBofXUdUzGw5B0Q==' | cut -d= -f2-
NDhhHcsOBofXUdUzGw5B0Q==
```

Here, you're taking fields from the 2nd to the end.

GNU grep with perl regular expressions would also work:

```
pw=$(grep -oP '^PASSWORD=\K.*' < filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Bash:

```
while read line ; do
  case $line in
    PASSWORD=*)
      echo "${line#PASSWORD=}" ;;
  esac
done < "$PASSWORD.ini"
```

The `${variable#text}` part strips the `text` from the `variable`.

Answer (score 2):

There's several nice ways you can do this within awk depending on the particular approach that suits you:

Change your FS:

```
$ echo 'PASSWORD=NDhhHcsOBofXUdUzGw5B0Q==' | awk -FPASSWORD= '{print $2;}'
NDhhHcsOBofXUdUzGw5B0Q==
```

Or change your ORS (this is REALLY hacky):

```
$ echo 'PASSWORD=NDhhHcsOBofXUdUzGS="="; ORS="=";} {for (i=2;i<NF;i++) print $i}'
NDhhHcsOBofXUdUzGw5B0Q==
```

The robust and generic way:

```
$ echo 'PASSWORD=NDhhHcsOBofXUdUzGw5B0Q==' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="^[^=]+=";} {print $2;}'
NDhhHcsOBofXUdUzGw5B0Q==
```

or (in the case of parsing >1 line and finding the one for which you are searching):

```
$ echo -e 'foo=bar\nPASSWORD=NDhhHcsOBofXUdUzGw5B0Q==\nbaz=quux\n\n' | \
  awk 'BEGIN {FS="^[^=]+=";} /^PASSWORD=/ {print $2;}'
NDhhHcsOBofXUdUzGw5B0Q==
```

Comment: Isn't missing the `awk` call itself from the second code block?

Comment: … which is handled by the final example.

Comment: Oops, indeed. Sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` you are not limited to splitting on single characters. So you could split on `D=` for example or even `PASSWORD=`:

```
password=$(awk -F "D=" '{print $2}' $PASSWORD.ini)
```

or

```
password=$(awk -F "PASSWORD=" '{print $2}' $PASSWORD.ini)
```

Answer (score 1):

And here's a Perl one:

```
pw=$(perl -ne 'print $1 if /PASSWORD=(.+)/' "$PASSWORD.ini")
```